# Cannot input text for an Edittext view inside a Popupwindow?

Tags: android, android-edittext, popupwindow, android-dialog

I want to enter text from soft keyboard to an Edittext widget inside a popupwindow, but I'm struggling with some problems. 
My activity is a game-card table, and enable some animations on that. In the gametable, there are some buttons. If player click on certain button, a popupwindow will be shown. The problem is player cannot input text to Edittext inside a popupwindow. I found some similar issues about this, and the most popular suggestion is :

```
Popupwindow.setFocusable(true)
```

With this setting, I can input normally to Edittext. However, this will block main UI thread and cause stop the animation in game table.I don't want this happen because it's bad for user experience.
It's possible to show softkeyboard when edittext has focus using below code snippet. However, I can not input anything from keyboard to edittext. Moreover, when I close popupwindow, the keyboard still show and not close.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)ct.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                    imm.showSoftInput(v, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                }
            }
        });
```

Please help me find the way to input data to Edittext without blocking animation in mainUI thread. The alternative way is to use custom dialog but it no help. Using dialog cause blocking mainUI thread too.
Thank you so much for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to block the UI try running this part of your code under a thread.
AsyncTask will be a good choice.

Check how to use AsyncTask here :-> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Good Luck

Comment: Could you say more details? In my case, I don't have anything that need to process in background then update to UI thread. So maybe AsyncTask is not suitable in this case.